# Visual Studio 2012 is extremely slow at startup

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012

Now it takes about 5 minutes to start the IDE itself and no project is loaded.

I have tried the following

- re install VS2012
- Remove Resharper
- Remove DevExpress

I have studied the activity log and found that record #945 takes about 8 minutes. Can anyone help?

[The same symptom is also described here but not answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782072/visual-studio-hangs-on-loading-ui-library)

```
  <entry>
    <record>944</record>
    <time>2013/08/01 09:52:36.493</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual Studio Logging Package]</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>945</record>
    <time>2013/08/01 09:52:50.670</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11D2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}</guid>
    <path>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\IDE*\VsLogUI.dll</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>946</record>
    <time>2013/08/01 10:00:55.206</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{F384B236-B4A9-401B-BC58-3106E3ACA3EC}</guid>
  </entry>
```

Comment: `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs` fixed a similar problem for me, but that's all I've got :)

Comment: You have a sick machine.  You need a doctor, not a programmer.  Look for network timeouts.

Comment: hi @JoachimIsaksson, i tried to launch with /ResetSkipPkgs but does not solve my problem. thanks anyway

Comment: From [this page](http://blog.geocortex.com/2007/12/07/slow-visual-studio-performance-solved/): try running [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) while loading VS, then isolate devenv.exe and see if there's any entries that look odd. It's super spammy but it may help in some way. The blog author found that his WebSiteCache directory had more than 10,000 folders in it.

Answer (score 4):

What seemed to help for me was dumping my temporary internet files and deleting the contents my `C:\FusionLogs`

The following registry keys can tell you if Fusion Logging is enabled and where it logs too:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\EnableLog   <-- logging set to exception
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\ForceLog    <-- log all binds to disk
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\LogFailures <-- log failures
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\LogPath     <-- target of logging
```

Comment: I COMPLETELY forgot that I'd enabled this - DOH!  Thanks for the tip - I hadn't even thought about this since I'm usually good about remembering to disable it when I'm done.